# yum install wireshark-gnome fails with failed to set locale, defaulting to C

Tags: fedora, yum

Please note - this is a new problem and doesn't have an answer within stackoverflow. I have checked it thoroughly. Also in google. so please do not negate this question.

I tried doing a yum install wireshark-gnome  on Fedora 13. (Please do not advise on using latest fedora etc., It is not in my control )

It fails with "failed to set locale, defaulting to C"

I understand that the locale settings are wrong. Tried to reinstall glibc-common by doing "yum re-install glibc-common". Even that fails with the same error "failed to set locale, defaulting to C".

For some users, it has worked but for me even a yum re-install of glibc-common gives me the same error. please let me know if you have any ideas.

I have tried localedef command in fedora and still no use.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i think i found the issue. First the /etc/resolv.conf did not have the right gateway IP. so was not able to connect to the internet.

Secondly, i had the contents in /etc/yum.repos.d moved. so yum install works now. Although the locale problem still present.